# Increase precision of Bokeh slider

Tags: python, bokeh, astronomy

I'm working on a Bokeh application that will eventually be used by students to find periodic signals in a time series (an astronomical light curve in this case). I have a slider for the period, and then the plot displays a phase-folded version of the time series. However, I want the slider to have high precision; in my code currently, I set up the slider as follows

```
period = Slider(title="period", value=2, start=1, end=3, step=0.0001)
```

However, in practice, I can't move the slider in increments less than 0.01, or very occasionally it seems to move a bit less than that. How can I increase the slider precision? I don't want to narrow the slider's range too much, because I ultimately don't want to hint at the true period when my students use this.

(The full code is here: https://github.com/stephtdouglas/orbit_phaser/blob/master/eclipse.py)

Comment: I don't use Bokeh, but I would assume the resolution is based on the slider's width. There are 20,000 steps between 1 and 3 with a step size of 0.0001. But if the slider is only 100 pixels wide (for example) it has to map those 20K steps down to 100. (Just my guess - I could be wrong).

Comment: I think you're running into a bokeh bug, the underlying slider truncates the precision of the step to two decimal places: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7349